# Lucene how to process the text and leave punctuation marks? (like create customAnalyzer or anything else)

Tags: java, lucene

I have a text:

```
created: 2003-09-22T19:01:14Z
Author: be590_guest

GUERRILLA WAR, COUNTERINSURGENCY, AND STATE 

FORMATION IN OTTOMAN YEMEN
```

Idea: I wanna to split it into words and don't delete punctuation marks, so that at the end I have the following:

```
ListWord[0]: created:
ListWord[1]: 2003
ListWord[2]: 09
ListWord[3]: 22t19
ListWord[4]: 01
ListWord[5]: 14z
ListWord[6]: author:
ListWord[7]: be590_guest
ListWord[8]: guerrilla
ListWord[9]: war,
ListWord[10]: counterinsurgency,
ListWord[11]: and
ListWord[12]: state
ListWord[13]: formation
ListWord[14]: in
ListWord[15]: ottoman
ListWord[16]: yemen
```

But the standard analyzer

```
Analyzer analyzer = new StandardAnalyzer()
```

removes punctuation marks, and use delete stop words. I try to create my custom analyzer (without stop words):

```
            Analyzer customAnalyzer = CustomAnalyzer.builder()
                .withTokenizer("standard")
                .addTokenFilter("lowercase")
                .addTokenFilter("porterstem")
                .addTokenFilter("capitalization")
                .build();
```

And i have output:

```
ListWord[0]: created
ListWord[1]: 2003
ListWord[2]: 09
ListWord[3]: 22t19
ListWord[4]: 01
ListWord[5]: 14z
ListWord[6]: author
ListWord[7]: be590_guest
ListWord[8]: guerrilla
ListWord[9]: war
ListWord[10]: counterinsurgency
ListWord[11]: and
ListWord[12]: state
ListWord[13]: formation
ListWord[14]: in
ListWord[15]: ottoman
ListWord[16]: yemen
```

---

How to process the text and leave punctuation marks? (use my customAnalyzer or create anything else)

Answer (score 0):

The "standard" tokenizer will remove the punctuation.
You can write your own Tokenizer implementation or, perhaps, use a `PatternTokenizer`.

A `PatternTokenizer` takes a regular expression `Pattern` for matching tokens (words) in the input. It also takes a group number (the index of the capturing group in the regular expression).
You could define your tokens to include any punctuation that you want to allow.